# How to fix build error com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I am getting the below exception when building the extjs4.1 project. Can anybody tell me how to avoid it? I am using sencha command version3.0. Using command

```
sencha app build


[ERR]           D:\TestProduction\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:213: com.sencha.exc
eptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 100 :
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue running sencha app build:

> ```
> [...]
> [INF] loading page .../static/sass/example/theme.html
> failed to render widgets within 30 sec.
>
> [ERR]
> [ERR] BUILD FAILED
> [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 1
> [ERR]
> [ERR] Total time: 49 seconds
> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
> .../static/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:469: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 1
> ```

It seemed that my project directory was missing the `sass` folder.

So I created a new app and copied over the sass folder from there:

> ```
> $ cd /tmp
> $ sencha -s ~/develop/js/Sencha/ext-4.2.1.883 generate app MyApp myapp
> $ tree myapp/sass
> myapp/sass
> ├── config.rb
> ├── etc
> ├── example
> │   ├── bootstrap.css
> │   ├── custom.js
> │   ├── render.js
> │   └── theme.html
> ├── src
> └── var
> $ cp -r myapp/sass <dest>
> ```

I also tried to copy the sass folder directly out of the `ext` folder within my app:

> $ cp -r ext/packages/ext-theme-classic/sass .

But it seems that some paths are not set. So I had to manually edit the file `theme.html`:

> ```
> $ vim sass/example/theme.html
>
> [...]
> <!--
> These links need to match the ext sdk from the current project
> -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />
> <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
> ```

After this, I was able again to do `sencha app build`:

```
$ sencha app build
[...]

[INF] loading page .../static/sass/example/theme.html
Capturing screenshot
Saving slicer widget manifest
Capture complete

[INF] Capture complete
[INF]      [echo] Slicing theme images to .../static/build/CreateProduct/production/resources
[INF] Including theme package ext-theme-classic for app.theme=ext-theme-classic build
[INF] Slicing images...
[INF] Slicing complete - generated 0 images
[INF]
[INF] -after-slice:
[INF]
[INF] -build:
[INF]
[INF] -after-build:
[INF]
[INF] build:
[INF]
[INF] app-build:
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it seemed to relate to a client path, that contained "#" in the path name ie c:\projects\c#\project\client

generating app in a different directory solved the issue